# How do I use a match statement to pattern match the class of multiple values in python?

Tags: python, switch-statement, pattern-matching, union-types, pyright

I have a union type, and I can create a value for it like so:

```
import random

class X:
    s: str = 'ab'
MyType = int | X

def get_value() -> MyType:
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        return 3
    return X()

a = get_value()
```

And I can use a match statement to pattern match on the class:

```
match a:
    case int():
        print(a + 1)
    case X():
        print(a.s)
```

But I want to be able to match on multiple variables at the same time. The typical way to do this in other languages is with a tuple, but I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly:

```
a = get_value()
b = get_value()

match a, b:
    case (int(),int()):
        print(a + 1)   # <-- Operator "+" not supported for types "MyType" and "Literal[1]"
    case (X(), X()):
        print(a.s)     # <-- Cannot access member "s" for type "int"
```

The code does run with `python3.12`, but the above errors are shown when I'm using the language server `pyright 1.1.282`. Is there a problem with my code? Is there a way to do this that avoids diagnostic errors in my editor?

Comment: Surely this must be an issue with pyright and not Python *per se*. [ adding pyright tag ]

Comment: It seems pyright is just wrong. You should file a bug with maintainers of pyright. To fill a bug, you should use a stable python version instead of alpha - 3.12 is in alpha right now, but the code works fine in 3.11 (latest stable python version) and 3.10 (which introduced pattern matching).

Comment: @h4z3 MyPy on 3.11 also raises same errors.

Answer (score 0):

With explicit `isinstance` check the error should be gone:

```
match a,b:
    case tuple() if isinstance(a, int):
        print(a + 1)
    case tuple() if isinstance(a, X):
        print(a.s)
```